# Radial gradient texture not working

Tags: color

I added radial gradient to this 2D object and it seems just like a normal linear gradient. I used the node setup screenshotted below. How to make it look like a radial gradient?
[image: This is the object and it certainly doesn't look like a radial gradient]

[image: node setup part 1]

[image: node setup part 2]

[image: I want a gradient like this]

[image: That is not the desired effect either (skipped separate XYZ in this node setup)]jHG.png

Comment: Hello, what result do you want exactly, don't you want Spherical or Quadratic Sphere instead?

Comment: You're only referring to 1 dimension of your texture-space, so you're only getting 1 dimension of  variation.  Ctrl-X lose the _Separate XYZ_ node, to give the _Gradient_ the whole vector..  (or at least, X and Y)

Comment: @moonboots see the edited question for the gradient I am referring to

Comment: @RobinBetts let me try it. How to give BOTH x and y though?

Comment: @SledgeCR so Quadratic Sphere is not what you want?

Comment: Hi, @SledgeCR ..  Feed the X and Y of the shading-point  as parameters to your texture with Z at some fixed value. probably 0.  Scale 1,1,0 in your _Mapping_ node, or  _Separate XYZ_ & _Combine XYZ_ with Z not cconnected, or _Vector Math > Multiply_ by (1,1,0) .. or _Map Range (Vector)_ with Z mapped to 0,0 ... etc. etc. (It looks as if your object-space Z is 0, anyway, so just plug in the whole vector) . BTW.  as moonboots has said .. 'Radial' will give you a clock-face sweep from 0-1, not a fade-from-center.

Comment: For a linear fade from object-origin, you could forget the _Gradient_ and just use a _Vector Math > Scale of the _Vector Math > Length_ of the Object coordinate.

Comment: @RobinBetts can you please explain the above comment in more detail? I haven't used vector math before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Object' coordinates are measured in Blender Units from the object origin,before any object-level transforms. (If you scale the *object* in Object Mode, the texture will scale with it. If you scale the *mesh* in Edit Mode, the texture will stay where it was)

Here are 2 ways .. one uses *Gradient > Quadratic Sphere* , taking as input the X and Y of 'Object' coordinates as input. Or, you could just use the length of the XY vector to the shading-point from the object origin.

[image]

In both of these examples, the Z coordinate is set to 0, which may be unnecessary, if the object measures 0 in Z anyway. The XY part has to be scaled, to fit the 0-1 range of the *Color-Ramp* input, one way or another.

[image]

[image]